# How to sort multidimensional array - list by matching string elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I try to find positions in list - data[i][2] if the string equal with the others string values, but if there are more than two of the same values, I do not want duplicates. And then I want to sort list. I need to keep the position of the first wanted for sort.

Thanks for help.

**INPUT:**

```
data = [["something1", 1, "number one", "inf 1",1, 33,22, "other"],
        ["something2",2, "number twenty", "inf 2", 1,66, 11, "other"],
        ["something3",3, "number one", "inf 3", 1,99, 55, "other"],
        ["something4",4, "number five", "inf 4", 1, 1212, 9988, "other"],
        ["something5",3, "number four", "inf 3", 1,99, 55, "other"],
        ["something6",3, "number one", "inf 3", 1,99, 55, "other"],
        ["something7",3, "number twenty", "inf 3", 1,99, 55, "other"]]

listMatch = []
for i in range(len(data)):

    for j in range(i+1, len(data)-1):

        if data[i][2] in data[j+1][2]:
            if len(listMatch) == 0:
                listMatch.append([i, j+1])
            if len(listMatch) > 0:
                if ([i, j+1]) not in listMatch:
                    listMatch.append([i, j+1])


            #print(data[i][2],(i, "Position of search value"), (j+1, "Position of found value"))
print(listMatch)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[[0, 2], [0, 5], [1, 6], [2, 5]]
```

**GOAL 1:**

```
[[0, 2], [0, 5], [1, 6]]
```

**GOAL 2:**

```
data = [["something1", 1, "number one", "inf 1",1, 33,22, "other"],
        ["something3",3, "number one", "inf 3", 1,99, 55, "other"],
        ["something6",3, "number one", "inf 3", 1,99, 55, "other"],
        ["something2",2, "number twenty", "inf 2", 1,66, 11, "other"],
        ["something7",3, "number twenty", "inf 3", 1,99, 55, "other"],        
        ["something4",4, "number five", "inf 4", 1, 1212, 9988, "other"],
        ["something5",3, "number four", "inf 3", 1,99, 55, "other"]]
```

Comment: What do you mean by *if the string value agrees with the others string values*?

Comment: @Guy I edited my question. If string on positions data[i][2] equal with others, I need to know positions and then get together (sort)

Comment: Why the `[2, 5]`is left out but not the `[0, 5]`?

Comment: @DaniMesejo becouse sort. And if there are three matches, I need to get together. See GOAL 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hence the answer (shortest i can come up with):

```
data = [["something1", 1, "number one", "inf 1",1, 33,22, "other"],
        ["something2",2, "number two", "inf 2", 1,66, 11, "other"],
        ["something3",3, "number one", "inf 3", 1,99, 55, "other"],
        ["something4",4, "number three", "inf 4", 1, 1212, 9988, "other"],
        ["something5",3, "number four", "inf 3", 1,99, 55, "other"],
        ["something6",3, "number one", "inf 3", 1,99, 55, "other"],
        ["something7",3, "number two", "inf 3", 1,99, 55, "other"]]

data = sorted(data, key=lambda element: element[2])

for i in data:
    print(i)
```

This does not fulfil the first goal but you would have to explain what you want better first.

Comment: Thanks for hint. But I do not know names (numbers) of data[i][2] there can be any string...

Comment: @Pr.Syn I changed this to sort strings in general, you really confused me with that example.

Comment: thanks, I found  (sorted(data, key=itemgetter(2))) - that is the same result. But I need to keep the position of the first wanted for sort - like in GOAL 2.